# How to setup Adyen acquirer account

Tags: api, adyen

I have a problem with testing *MB WAY for API only* payment method on Adyen https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/mb-way/api-only

After I send request as described here https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/mb-way/api-only#make-payment

```
curl https://checkout-test.adyen.com/v68/payments \
-H 'x-api-key: YOUR_API_KEY' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d '{
  "merchantAccount": "YourCompanyECOM",
  "reference": "My first Adyen test payment",
  "amount": {
    "value": 1000,
    "currency": "EUR"
  },
    "paymentMethod": {
    "type": "scheme",
    "encryptedCardNumber": "test_4111111111111111",
    "encryptedExpiryMonth": "test_03",
    "encryptedExpiryYear": "test_2030",
    "encryptedSecurityCode": "test_737"
  }
}'
```

I receive this response

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "errorCode": "905_1",
    "message": "Could not find an acquirer account for the provided txvariant (mbway), currency (EUR), and action (AUTH).",
    "errorType": "configuration",
    "pspReference": "GBSGRNJVSBLZNN82"
}
```

I did not found a way to set up an **acquirer account** on Adyen dashboard so far. Is that option there, or I need to do something else to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of error can have as origin one of the following reasons:

- The currency is not configured or supported
- The minimum amount is set too low
- The payment method is not configured on your account
- The payment type (shopperInteraction) is not supported.

The full documentation of this error is [here](https://www.adyen.help/hc/en-us/articles/360014243600-Why-do-I-receive-a-905-Payment-details-are-not-supported-error-)

Comment: In my case it was the payment method. I configured some other payment method by mistake, thinking it is for MB Way.

Thank you!